# C++ Eclipse CDT How to add gcc 4.6.3

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, gnu, eclipse-cdt

I am running Eclipse CDT in Redhat Enterprise, the default version of gcc compiler is 4.4.6. The support team added gcc 4.6.3 recently, I am wondering how can I set up Eclipse in such a way that I can choose to compile the application with either gcc 4.4.6 or 4.6.3.

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't eclipse use the system default? I mean, for compiling.

Comment: When I look at the auto-generated makefiles, g++ is called to do the compiling. That should call the g++ version that you call when you type g++ in a terminal, right?

Comment: Yes, it does. The current setup in Eclipse is to use gcc 4.4.6. I am wondering how can I setup another gcc version, e.g., 4.6.3, so that I can choose which version to compile with. Or how can I add another GNU C++ toolchain in Eclipse. Thanks.

Comment: The support team decides to keep both version of the gcc, in case some other user may still want to use 4.4.6.

Comment: I'm sure some hardcore eclipse user will come and give a better answer, but I'd make a folder named `local` in my home folder, create in it a symbolic link called `g++` to `/usr/bin/g++4.6.3` and start eclipse saying `PATH=~/local:$PATH eclipse`. If you want to always compile with 4.6.3 you could also export this path in ~/.bashrc.

Answer (score 6):

If you really want both gcc 4.6 and 4.4 in your eclipse, you will have to adjust your build configurations (as far I know there is no "easy" way to do this by default).

> Project -> Properties -> C/C+++ Build -> Manage Configurations -> create new

Once this is created (& selected) you set it just like other configurations in tree (Debug / Release).

> new_configuration > Discovery -> Compiler invocation command --> set path to gcc 4.6

I believe you have to do this per each project, Eclipse is sloppy in this area.

Answer (score 1):

I've just follow this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291369/set-up-eclipse-c-compiler-without-auto-install-or-altering-system-path-on-wind) and done that succesfully for Eclipse empty make project.
Try adding or editing PATH variable under
"Project property" => "C/C++ Build"  => "Environment".
This way you don't need to alter environment variable outside the Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can have two versions configured in default CDT distribution. It will use the system default. What do you get if you do gcc -v? I guess 4.4.6. Put 4.6 in PATH before that, and it will use 4.6.
And do restart eclipse, after you modify the path.

Also see [this on how to clear project "discovery profile"](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#I_installed_a_new_version_of_my_compiler_but_old_include_paths_of_old_compiler_are_still_there_under_.22Paths_and_Symbols.22_in_project_properties._I_cannot_get_rid_of_them.21_What_do_I_edit_to_remove_the_old_paths_by_hand.3F).

Comment: yes, it is still showing 4.4.6. Where can I modify PATH variable? I am running Redhat Enterprise Linux. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, in Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> GNU C++, it is all using 4.4.6 now. Once I change the PATH, and restart the Eclipse, will it automatically be changed to 4.6.3? Thanks.

Comment: Try adding it to .profile (in your home). Something like export PATH=/new/toolchain/path:${PATH}