# Eclipse C/C function 'printf' could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

I'm trying to set up a C/C++ development environment on Eclipse.

I installed the following Eclipse plugins:

- C/C++ development tools SDK
- Library API documentation hover help
- Unit testing support
- Compiler support

Then download [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).

I followed this for set up: *[Set up Eclipse C++ compiler without auto-install or altering System Path on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291369/set-up-eclipse-c-compiler-without-auto-install-or-altering-system-path-on-wind)*
then:

```
Menu *Project* ? *Properties* ? *"C/C++ Include Paths and Symbols"* ? *"Add External Include path...". I added these paths:
C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.0\include
C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.0\include\c++
C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.0\include\c++\backward
C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.0\include\c++\mingw32
C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.0\include-fixed
```

It still gives me a "Function 'printf' could not be resolved" error or any other function for that matter.

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!!!!");
    return 0;
}
```

When I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, Eclipse gives me suggestions for C++ functions, but it gives the same error when I select them. It's probably a simple settings change. It would be really helpful if you could help me figure this out.

Answer (score 7):

You must include `<stdio.h>` above your main(). This should solve it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello World!!!");
    return 0;
}
```

---

Sometimes, Eclipse's parser gets stupid. You can try reparsing the project. Right click on your project then → *Index* → *Rebuild*. After rebuild, most likely the symbols will be recognized.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that. I have that too.

Comment: I had the same problem and "Right click on the project then ->Index->Rebuild" worked for me after restarting Eclipse.

Comment: Restarting Eclipse worked for me. Try Clean and Build the project.

Answer (score 0):

You must include

```
C:\MinGW\include
```

to the include directory for using C functions.

Comment: I have that. The first stackoverflow link mentions that.

Comment: I'm saying that you didn't add that directory to the Eclipse include directories. Also `MinGW\mingw32\ ` doesn't have an `include` directory.

Comment: Do you mean : 
Project->Properties->"C/C++ Include Paths and Symbols"->"Add" C:\MinGW\include. I did this. Please let me know if you mean someting else.
I pasted that from another site, I included all others except for MinGW\mingw32\.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. C includes are stored in that directory.